# DotVVM - HttpContext.Current debe ser distinto de null cuando se proporciona RequestContext

Tags: c#, webforms, mvvm

Estoy intentando utilizar un routelink a una página aspx desde una view de DotVVM. Ya tengo instalado el paquete de Adapters, completé el startup.cs y el global.asax.cs.

El error se produce en el `webforms:routeLink`.

> He probado con quitar el gridView y el método preRender en el ViewModel, dejando sólo el weforms:routeLink harcodeado y funciona sin problemas.

¡Agradezco la ayuda!

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationExceptionHttpContext.Current debe ser distinto de null cuando se proporciona RequestContext.
> <webforms:RouteLink RouteName="VistaCaso" Param-idCaso="{value: IdCaso}">
>                                                                VistaCaso
>                                                            </webforms:RouteLink>
>
> DotVVM.Framework.Controls.DotvvmControlExceptionError occurred in Render method
> ```

---

```
<dot:GridView DataSource="{value: ListadoCasos}" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <Columns>
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: Numero}" HeaderText="Número" AllowSorting="true" SortExpression="Numero" HeaderCssClass="text-primary" CssClass="text-primary" />
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: FechaIngreso}" HeaderText="Fecha" AllowSorting="true" SortExpression="FechaIngreso" FormatString="dd/MM/yyyy" HeaderCssClass="text-primary" />
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: Caratula}" HeaderText="Carátula" AllowSorting="true" SortExpression="Caratula" HeaderCssClass="text-primary" />
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: Estado}" HeaderText="Estado" AllowSorting="true" SortExpression="Estado" HeaderCssClass="text-primary" />
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: Fiscal}" HeaderText="Fiscal" AllowSorting="true" SortExpression="Fiscal" HeaderCssClass="text-primary" />
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: Funcionario}" HeaderText="Funcionario letrado" AllowSorting="true" SortExpression="Funcionario" HeaderCssClass="text-primary" />
        <dot:GridViewTextColumn ValueBinding="{value: Administrativo}" HeaderText="Administrativo referente" AllowSorting="true" SortExpression="Administrativo" HeaderCssClass="text-primary" />
        <dot:GridViewTemplateColumn AllowSorting="false">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <webforms:RouteLink RouteName="VistaCaso" Param-idCaso="{value: IdCaso}">
                    VistaCaso
                </webforms:RouteLink>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </dot:GridViewTemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        Sin resultados
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</dot:GridView>
<dot:DataPager DataSet="{value: ListadoCasos}" HideWhenOnlyOnePage="true" class="pager" />
```